# Set listen port for file communication

Tags: c#, networking, listener, dicom, fo-dicom

I am extremely new to network communication and need to understand listening ports better. I have to create an application that listens for incoming DICOM associations. However I am unsure about which port I should listen on or if it really even matters.

I read [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) that there are specific ports for DICOM communication (ports 104, 4242, 11112). does my decision for which port to use have to be one of those three, or are these just the standard?

Comment: You have to listen to whatever port(s) the clients expect to connect to. 101 will require root access.

Comment: Anything DICOM is buy, not build.  The typical hospital bill I get pays for it.

Comment: 4242 corresponds to the unprivileged port that is used by default by the Orthanc DICOM server. You might be interested by reading [this section of the Orthanc Book](https://orthanc.chu.ulg.ac.be/book/dicom-guide.html#dicom-network-protocol).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no standard port for DICOM network communication, but there are so called well-known ports. These are 104 and 11112; 4242 is no officially assigned well-known port number for DICOM.

You could use 104 (which requires root privileges on Unix systems) or 11112 (which does not) as a default port number for your Service Class Provider (SCP). But please make sure that the port number is configurable!

Answer (score 2):

DICOM reserved the following TCP and UDP port numbers from Internet Assigned Numbers Authority:

- Port 104 - well-known port for DICOM over TCP or UDP.
- Port 2761 - registered for DICOM using Integrated Secure Communication Layer (ISCL) over TCP or UDP.
- Port 2762 - registered for DICOM using Transport Layer Security (TLS) over TCP or UDP.
- Port 11112 - registered for DICOM using standard, open communication over TCP or UDP.